# How to change Awesome Icons position in topnav when Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How my menu currently looks like:
[what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVV96.jpg)
What i want:
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k7Rj.jpg)
When i resize my window screen and the menu buttons/links start to move to another line i added a media query to make it all in one button. When you click that button all the menu options show. I need help to aligne the awesome icons and the website links so it wont take up that much space.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #63757a;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.699999988079071044921875;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000000;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/index.html" title="hjem">Home</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/media.html" title="Media">Media</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/gallery.html" title="Bilder">Bilder</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/trening.html" title="trening">Trening</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/kontakt.html" title="kontakt meg">Kontakt meg</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/registration.php" title="registrer deg">Registrer deg</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/login.php" title="login her">Logg inn</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/dashboard.php" title="ditt dashboard">Dashboard</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/skole.html" title="se skole siden min">Skole</a>
  <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=therealsirwerty%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe%2FOslo" title="åpne kalender på ny side">Kalender</a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sirwerty" title="facebook" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/hvardpettersen1" title="twitter" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/oldwildybck" title="youtube" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/realsirwerty/" title="instagram" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/havard.boy" title="snapchat" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Sir_Werty/" title="reddit" class="fa fa-reddit"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve. what is the behavior your trying to get? don't you want the topnav to be responsive always?

Comment: It just looks like both could be used on either small or large screen... I'm not sure if you're trying to get both working with a media query, or is something missing from the photos you added?

Comment: I dont want every link or icon to take up 100% width so example: media/gallery on 1 line under it is 2 more etc etc

Comment: Fixed it abit to somewhere i wanted: @media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
.topnav.responsive {

position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000000;

    
width:100%;
display : flex;
flex-wrap : wrap;

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the icons out of screen instead of breaking them to another line when you resize the window to be smaller?

Comment: No i want them there but all on 1 line

Comment: I got this now https://imgur.com/a/7SZXw

Answer (score 1):

If you want your only icons in a row try this css

```
.topnav.responsive a[class*=fa] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

It will target all the anchor tags which class name contain the `fa` substring

***Stack Snippet***

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #63757a;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.699999988079071044921875;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a[class*=fa] {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000000;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/index.html" title="hjem">Home</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/media.html" title="Media">Media</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/gallery.html" title="Bilder">Bilder</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/trening.html" title="trening">Trening</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/kontakt.html" title="kontakt meg">Kontakt meg</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/registration.php" title="registrer deg">Registrer deg</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/login.php" title="login her">Logg inn</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/dashboard.php" title="ditt dashboard">Dashboard</a>
  <a href="https://www.havardpettersen.life/skole.html" title="se skole siden min">Skole</a>
  <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=therealsirwerty%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe%2FOslo" title="åpne kalender på ny side">Kalender</a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sirwerty" title="facebook" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/hvardpettersen1" title="twitter" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/oldwildybck" title="youtube" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/realsirwerty/" title="instagram" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/havard.boy" title="snapchat" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Sir_Werty/" title="reddit" class="fa fa-reddit"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Im just gonna fix this myself pretty much fixed it already but ty